# Using WinToFlash to create bootable flash drive

Tags: windows, windows-7, usb-flash-drive

I have Windows XP but I want to upgrade to Windows 7. Since I have no DVD-ROM drive (only CD-ROM)
I used WinToFlash (v0.4.0021 beta) to create bootable flash drive with Windows 7. After Windows Setup Transfer Wizard completed I restarted the computer and then booted from USB drive.
And I get this message: "NTLDR is missing". I turned on Windows XP and searched the original disk of Windows 7 and the NTLDR wasnt there.
The disk is brand new and I have tested it on Virtual PC. No problems while installing it on the Virtual machine.
I used Kingston 8 GB flash drive.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) instead.

If you run into issues, follow the guide [Installing Windows 7 on a netbook](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/installing-windows-7-on-a-netbook).

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot from the flash disk with Windows 7.
2. Open the command prompt
3. Change to the `C:` drive
4. Type the following:

   ```
   bootrec /fixmbr
   ```
5. Then:

   ```
   bootrec /rebuildbcb
   ```
6. Exit and restart your computer.

If this does not work for you then, follow same procedures but now type:

```
bootrec /fixboot.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different flash drive.  I had a different problem using a Kingston 16GB USB3.0 flash drive that would boot to the drive but fail during the install process.

Using a 4GB ScanDisk USB2.0 (although probably almost any other non-Kingston USB drive would work) the install worked fine.

see: [Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition - Can't install Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/789255/setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition-or-locate-an-existing-system-p/835869#835869)

Comment: Yeah, when I was updating firmware on my SSD, the installer which made the flash drive bootable for PC in order to flash the firmware, didn't work on that particular drive, other drives  worked fine. I don't have time to try this but if I do, I will accept this answer. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

**WinToFlash**
Do not use the wizard mode and Use Advanced Mode -> Select Transfer Windows 7 setup to USB Drive -> Create ->
In the Format tab Select FAT16LBA
and run to completion
used to boot the PC and do not click Install
take your usb
Make the installer again with FAT32LBA
then plug it in again

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use DISKPART to make the partition on your flash drive active/bootable.

```
Dead simple way to make a bootable flash drive:
1) Run DISKPART from an admin console window
2) Type LIST DISK and find your USB drive on the list based on size
3) Type SELECT DISK *, with * being whatever number your thumbdrive is listed as
4) Type SELECT PARTITION 1
5) Type ACTIVE
6) Format the thumbdrive to the FAT32 spec
```

Now your thumbdrive can be booted from if it contains the proper files. Now copy the entire contents of your Win7 DVD to the thumbdrive and you're good to go.

I've always wondered why people make the process needlessly complex by using a tool to do this.

[More detailed Explaination Here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jeffloucks/archive/2009/10/08/creating-usb-bootable-using-diskpart-and-using-it-to-install-windows-7.aspx)