# Error installing Windows - Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition

Tags: windows-7, installation

I am trying to install Windows on my computer. I previously had Ubuntu and Kali Linux installed. I am able to boot up from my USB. I agree to all the legal stuff and when it comes to installing Windows, I get this error:

> Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an
>   existing system partition

I have tried several different times and used several different USB booting tools.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here's a link to a picture of my error:

[image]

Comment: You need to mark the disk 0 partition as the primary partition.

Comment: Is the system in UEFI mode, or Legacy BIOS?  I also find it a little odd that you have "70GB" disks, what kind of disks are these?

Comment: This isn't a picture of my computer, just my error at the bottom. And i don't know.what is uefi and bios mode

Comment: @jo900 - Do some research.  You never made any mention that this wasn't your screnshot.  You will have to provide us exact information from your system if you want specific help in that case.  Of course the error in question, is caused by, not having an primary partition.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on Drive options(advanced)...?

Comment: If it helps anyone, the "setup log files" are at: `%WINDIR%\Panther` more specifically (for disk) `setuperr.log`

Comment: I had the same problem but none of these solutions worked for me. I posted my solution in another thread because OP there was more thorough in what he tried before posting, covering all things I tried before finally solving my issue: http://superuser.com/questions/945600/windows-installation-couldnt-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one/1063268

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/789255/setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition-or-locate-an-existing-system-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the easiest way to do this:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open the command prompt
2. Run `DISKPART` to start Diskpart
3. Run `LIST DISK` to list disks available to wipe
4. Run `SELECT DISK 0` replacing `0` with the number of your disk
5. Run `CLEAN` to **fully wipe your hard drive**
6. Run `EXIT` twice to exit both Diskpart and Command Prompt
7. Hit `Refresh` at the `Where do you want to install Windows` prompt
8. Select the newly formatted drive to install Windows on.
9. Continue with the standard Windows install
10. Done

Answer (score 0):

Press Shift+F10 and use Diskpart tool to create a new partition.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300415

Open Command Prompt with Shift + F10 and use these steps to create a new partition manually:

1. diskpart
2. list disk
3. select disk [the disk number you want to install windows on, usually 0]
4. list partition
5. delete partition [all partitions (if there are no partitions, that's okay, just skip it.)]
6. clean
7. convert gpt [only if you use uefi]
8. create partition primary
9. format fs=ntfs quick
10. active

Close the command prompt, Click refresh on the Windows setup. You can now continue without any problem.

Comment: Can you summarise the steps here?