# Dual-boot Elementary OS Freya and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, elementaryos

I have ThinkPad with win7 preinstalled. I bought a new SSD and iserted it in a free slot and have Freya OS installed on this SSD.

Now I want to put win7 on SSD as well, so I created a 23GB NTFS partition. I use installation DVD. When I boot it, I select the custom install option. After selecting the desired partition and clicking next I get the following error:

Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition - Can't install Windows 7

This seems like a common error ([superuser question discussing this error](https://superuser.com/questions/789255/setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition-or-locate-an-existing-system-p)), however, all the solutions I have found include having only one single partition on my SSD (eg. [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2012/03/06/error-quot-we-couldn-t-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one-for-more-information-see-the-setup-log-files-quot-when-you-try-to-install-windows-8-cp.aspx)). Is there a way to go around this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating NTFS partition, leave free space. Windows 7 needs small partition(100 Mb) for bootmgr, so let installer make partitions automatically.

Also, make sure, that SATA Mode is set to ACHI in BIOS Setup, it's only correct mode for SSD.

Comment: SATA mode is set to ACHI and I tried what you suggested. No luck