# Windows 7 installation - setup was unable to create a system partition or locate an existing partition

Tags: windows-7, mbr, windows-installation, diskpart

I am trying to install Windows 7 from a bootable USB drive. I encountered the following error after selecting the partition to install Windows on:

> Setup was unable to create a system partition or locate an existing partition [...]

I cleaned all partitions, created a partition and formatted it but I still get the same error. Then I checked the logs at X:\Windows\panther\setupact.log (what a stupid directory!) and at the bottom it said along the lines,

> [...] The selected disk is not the computer's boot disk.

Indeed, when I checked in `diskpart`, by `det disk` it showed me the attributes of the disk, and Boot Disk has the value "No". I think, if I can set it to "yes", then my problem will be resolved. I will also note that my partition was marked "active" when I was doing all of this.

However diskpart has no option to set the boot flag. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Similar problem was solved by updating BIOS,[check this](http://superuser.com/questions/945600/windows-installation-couldnt-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one)

Comment: could it have anything to do with an Active flag?  diskpart, select disk # , select partition # , active.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like my BIOS supports USB installations. Otherwise I couldn't install my current OS.

Comment: @Psycogeek The only partition in the disk is marked active (as it should be)

Comment: You cannot set a disk to "boot". Boot is simply the description of what disk that copy of Windows booted from.

Comment: Active command makes the partition bootable. You might try assigning it a drive letter.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/789255/setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition-or-locate-an-existing-system-p